# xpath works for just the first image

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping this website 
http://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/buy/villa-for-sale-dubai-jumeirah-park-1849328.html?img/0

and I want to get all the image src in this tag `div[@id='propertyPhoto']`

I tried this xpath

```
.//div[@id='propertyPhoto']//img/@src
```

and them I make a loop to extract the src but I got only the first image src

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the main images is in the `div#propertyPhoto`. Others are inside `li#propertyPhotoMini0`, `li#propertyPhotoMini1`, ...

So XPath should slighly modified to match both. `id` attributes of them all starts with `propertyPhoto`; you can use following XPath:

```
.//*[starts-with(@id, 'propertyPhoto')]//img/@src
```

Example:

```
import urllib
from scrapy.selector import Selector
url = 'http://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/buy/villa-for-sale-dubai-jumeirah-park-1849328.html?img/0'
h = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
root = Selector(text=h, type='html')
for url in root.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'propertyPhoto')]//img/@src").extract():
    print(url)
```

output:

```
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-1-wide.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-1-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-2-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-3-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-4-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-5-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-6-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-7-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-8-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-9-mini.jpg
http://c1369023.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/1849328-10-mini.jpg
```

Comment: how could you get that result, I have just tested the xpath on the shell like this `s = sel.xpath(".//div[@id='propertyPhoto']//img/@src")`and then I check the `s` and I got the first image

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, I updated the answer. Please reload the page.

Comment: after your update, I got the correct images from shell. However, when I tried to get it from my spider like this `objects = sel.xpath(THE XPATH)
        for oneObject in objects:
            results.extend(oneObject.extract())` I got only the letters of the src.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Try `results = sel.xpath(THE_XPATH).extract()`

Comment: Yes i already tried that. actually that is what gives me the letters. I tried without extract but I got errro too

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, What do you mean you get letters? `['h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', ... 'j', 'p', 'g']` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Did you type exactly I did in the previous comment? It seems like you are iterating each element of `results`. Just try to print the `result` itself.

Comment: do u mean print the `oneObject` in my casse?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, `results = sel.xpath(THE_XPATH).extract(); print results`

Comment: I got this `["http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-1-wide.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-1-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-2-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-3-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-4-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-5-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-6-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-7-mini.jpg", "http://c1369021.r21.cf3.rackcdn.com/1864856-8-mini.jpg"]`

Comment: Yes problem solved, i don't need to make loop on them, the `results` is fine, thanks buddy

Comment: Hi, i have a problem in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099269/python-scrapy-change-the-name-of-the-output-file could you check it please?